# Internal Address working via VPN but external not

Tags: server, apache2

I have an ubuntu 17.10 server setup on a virtual machined.  I also have apache2, php5, mysql, and moodle.  I have everything setup and it is working fine when using ip address.... 10.0.0.4, moodle comes up just fine when I use the vpn... My problem is the external ip address of 17.25.17.98 (fake address) will not route to my internal address of 10.0.0.4 and ultimately to the moodle site I am setting up. The host says something is wrong with my apache or ubuntu setup, but I think it is ultimately a routing issue with the host site. Not my configuration files on Apache, Ubuntu or anything...  Suggestions please....

Comment: I do need to clarify that I am trying to come in from the external address and it is not routing in properly.

Comment: Well, I might know why...  Host loaded ubuntu 17 desktop, instead of server....   Unless desktop will work????